# Memoized solution to subarrays adding to k won't work

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem is: given an array `nums`, find the unique subarrays (need not be continuous) that add up to `k`. If I comment out the first `if` statement that checks for inclusion in the memo, everything works. With that line, it will not work. Can anyone help me figure out why? Thank you

```
class Solution:
    def unique_subarrays_sum(self, nums, k):
        self.memo = {}
        self.pool = sorted(nums)
        return self.helper([], 0, k)

    def first_idx(self, nums, start):
        seen = set()
        return [(idx, n) for idx, n in enumerate(nums, start) if n not in seen and not seen.add(n)]

    def helper(self, used, idx, k, call_num=0):
        if (idx, k) in self.memo:
            return self.memo[(idx, k)]
        elif k == 0:
            self.memo[(idx, k)] = [used]
            return self.memo[(idx, k)]
        elif k < 0:
            return []
        else:
            res = []
            # print('  '*call_num, self.first_idx(self.pool[idx:], idx), sep='')
            for i, e in self.first_idx(self.pool[idx:], idx):
                # print(f'{"  "*call_num}going to: used={used+[e]}, pool={self.pool[i+1:]}, k={k-e}')
                r = self.helper(used+[e], i+1, k-e, call_num+1)
                res.extend(r)

            self.memo[(idx, k)] = res
            # print(f'{"  "*call_num}found: {res}', end='\n')
            return res
```

An example where this doesn't work:

```
input = [4,1,1,4,4,4,4,2,3,5]
output, memoized (wrong) = [[1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 4, 4]]
output, no memo (correct) = [[1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Can you provide debugging details (e.g. a test case where this discrepancy occurs)?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark yes, just editted

Comment: I find it concerning that your function takes three significant parameters (I'm not counting `call_num`, which is basically cosmetic), yet your memo is keyed by only two of those parameters.  Unless `used` is somehow uniquely determined by the other two parameters, you will be returning inappropriate values when only `idx` and `k` match a previous call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `used` is being passed in when it should only be added to results after the computation

```
class Solution:
    def unique_subarrays_sum(self, nums, k):
        self.memo = defaultdict(list)
        self.pool = sorted(nums)
        return self.helper([], 0, k)

    def first_idx(self, nums, start):
        seen = set()
        return [(idx, n) for idx, n in enumerate(nums, start) if n not in seen and not seen.add(n)]

    def helper(self, used, idx, k):
        if (idx, k) in self.memo:
            return self.memo[(idx, k)]
        elif k == 0:
            return [used]
        elif k < 0:
            return []
        else:
            res = []
            for i, e in self.first_idx(self.pool[idx:], idx):
                r = [used + l for l in self.helper([e], i+1, k-e)]
                res.extend(r)
                
            self.memo[(idx, k)] = res
            return res
```